# avoid change location in anchor (html)

Tags: javascript, html

I am thinking about the best solution handling click events avoiding the change of the location in the browser(#).

These are the two scenarios:

```
1. <a class="someclass" href="#">Click me</a>
   (This is ok, but adds a "#" in the url)  

2.  <a class="someclass" href="javascript:void(0)">Click me</a>
   (Seems to be better, the url never changes, but I don't know about compatibility in all browsers, or even when javascript is disabled)
```

Which one is the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The `href` parameter isn't a requirement as far as I know. Just remove it and still hook up the events you need.

Answer (score 0):

In first method..Just add `return false` where you are handling the click event. Then it wont add `#` to URL

Answer (score 0):

use `Javascript:void(0);`.

The `void` operator was pretty much to only way force the click to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `href="javascript:void(0)"` in adjacent with `onClick` because it will prevent the browser from loading a new page.if you want to use `onCLick` for the hyperlink and require the client to not be direct to a new page after clicking on the hyperlink, return void(0) following `href='javascript:void(0)'` will prevent that to happen.